# PDF to wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, pdf

I am trying to convert a PDF file to a Wordpress post format, but I am not able to preserve the formatting. I am first converting my PDF to html using a PDF to HTML Java library, and then I copy the html code directly to the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor. But I am not able to preserve the formatting.

Can anybody explain to me how I would be able to preserve the HTML formatting in the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: In the general use case this is not possible, as PDF can easily include text as graphics.
Simplest solution would be to get the excerpt of the text from the PDF as a post, and provide the PDF for download.

Answer (score 0):

PDFs aren't web documents by nature, so their structural layout doesn't translate very well to a web environment. So with WordPress it's really hit-or-miss. A lot of elements wont translate well; you'll probably have to do some re-formatting yourself.